# interpreted java IDE environment

Tags: java, scripting, ide

In scripting languages like Ruby/Python/Perl, we can start an interactive session and create new variables, and essentially execute whatever statements.

But in Java, I only know of a way to print arbitrary expressions - in Eclipse's debug-expression view.

There is no way to create new vars, and later utilize that var (though you can assign to pre-existing vars).

Is there any way to run Java in a interpreted IDE environment just like scripting languages?

Answer (score 5):

Check out [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org). If you want to stick to pure Java, I think Groovy will happily execute any valid Java code. You can poke at it via the GroovySH  [interactive shell](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Shell).

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/)  It has been around a while.  Also you can look at [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/) website for an online IDE-like environment for several languages (not quite a shell).  And yeah, I meant to mention Groovy too, which has the groovy shell.

Answer (score 0):

As of Java 9 there will be a REPL available to allow you to start an interactive Java session.

It's called JShell, and you can read the original proposal: [JEP 222: jshell: The Java Shell (Read-Eval-Print Loop)](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/222)

There are a number of blogs and articles [exploring](http://jakubdziworski.github.io/java/2016/07/31/jshell-getting-started-examples.html) some of the [features](http://blog.takipi.com/java-9-early-access-a-hands-on-session-with-jshell-the-java-repl/) of JShell, if you'd like to see it in action.